# How to update variable in javascript/jquery after click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, var, updating

I am trying to write some code that only allows buttons with the .add class function on click if there are fewer than 3 immediate children divs within the #hold placeholder div. theDiv_append is a seperate function that adds a div block within #hold div placeholder. I am trying to update the countingdivs variable to then count and update the number of divs within #hold, but it's not working. Currently, the add button does not get disabled.

```
   var countingdivs = '1'; 
    if(countingdivs <= '2') {
  $(document).on('click',".add",theDiv_append);
    countingdivs = $("#hold > div").length;
   };
```

Any help would be great. Thanks!

Comment: this would be easier if you turn the variable into an object, that's if the answers below doesn't solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the condition to the click handler:

```
$(document).on('click', '.add', theDiv_append);

function theDiv_append() {
    var $hold = $('#hold'),
        len = $hold.children('div').length;

    if (len <= 2) {
      // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and works perfectly! Thank you very much. I'm still new to all this but moving the condition to the handler makes much more sense. Thank you again!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var countingdivs = 1; 
if(countingdivs <= 2) {
    $(document).on('click',".add", theDiv_append);
    countingdivs = $("#hold > div").length;
} else {
    $(document).off('click',".add", theDiv_append);
}
```

Maybe try assigning `countingdivs` with the current length of `#hold > div`

```
var countingdivs = $("#hold > div").length;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but wasn't quite what I was looking for.